# resize custom cell width as tableview frame

Tags: ios, uitableview

i am making a tableview with custom cell.but custom cell width never adjust with tableview frame with test with different device. does anyone could help.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    customTableViewCell * cell = (customTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray * nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
    cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 30);
    NSLog(@"tableview width: %f",tableView.frame.size.width);
    NSLog(@"cell width :%f" ,cell.frame.size.width);
    return cell;        
}
```

here cell frame is same as table view.

But! in customTableViewCell.m, awakeFromNib, the frame is still as same as in xib. PS: i don't want to change in xib, because i need to adapt different device.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSLog(@"%f awake from nib called",self.frame.size.width);
    self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    self.customLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, self.contentView.frame.size.height - 1.0, self.contentView.frame.size.width, 1)];

    self.customLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.customLine];
}
```

so here we have the problem, when i want to add a custom separator in awakeFromNib, cell's frame leads the problems.

Comment: Have you tried adding `self.customLine.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`?

Comment: @IanMacDonald yes i've tried but it doesn't help. In fact i make a mistake, i always try to adapt the size of cell. but in fact we don't care of the cell size, when i add   [self setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 40, 0, 0)];
it works prefect !! Thanks for you answer anyway.